# Why is my app not showing on Google Play? Just now published

Tags: android, xml, google-play, publish

I just tried to publish my app for the first time -

I went through the steps on Developer Console and it says "published" now with a green check mark (after I hit "activate" and "publish", with no errors)

However, I tried searching by name on the Google Play store ( it's called "Urbanary Challenge" ) on my phone, tablet, and chrome browser but nothing shows up. (same with company name search).

Then, I tried by direct URL:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shameless.studios.twisted.trivia

and the id is the "package name" under my AndroidManifest.xml like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.shameless.studios.twisted.trivia"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

However, I get an error saying "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publishing an App on Google Play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809682/publishing-an-app-on-google-play)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just wait. I've seen applications take up to 27 hours to hit the Play Store. (My current five each took about 15-45 minutes by URL, and about 2-3 hours by search.)

Comment: wow. okay. but how would i know if i had done something wrong? or is the "published" status on my Developer Console enough to tell me that i've done everything properly for submission? (im guess they'll tell me if i get rejected)

Comment: Unlike Apple, Google only "rejects" apps if they contain malware. Your application should be considered accepted as soon as you hit Save and see "Published".

Comment: gotcha. thanks a bunch. i finally see my app now, and it's even searchable by the app name or company!

Comment: My app cannot be found after 6 months. Google's in-store search algorithm is far behind, obviously. The app is called [mathe quiz](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mathe+quiz&c=apps&docType=1) with no match. The app can only be found using double quotes: ["mathe quiz"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%22mathe%20quiz%22&c=apps) (darkblue icon with MQ) - how weird.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV Yours shows up for me, but it's way down the list without quotes. (Probably the 100th result or so.)

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for letting me know. Sadly, in a usual case, super few users will scroll down so far and even click the "load more" button.

Answer (score 2):

It's not instantaneous, imagine your APK file has to be processed and synchronized with a lot of servers. Sometimes it takes around 15 minutes.

[]s
Neto