# App not showing in Google Play Store even thought its published and active in the developer console

Tags: android

I published my app last night.  It took several hours for it to show up, but eventually it did.  It's called "Interesting Wikipedia," but when you search those exact words, it doesn't show up.  The direct url works: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tierramaxis.interestingwikipedia

Any ideas?  The strange thing is, earlier this morning I searched and it was about the 5th entry in the results.  When I searched later though, it's not showing any more.  I scrolled through about 250 results and it never showed.

Comment: Here's a direct link to the search:

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=interesting%20wikipedia&c=apps

Comment: Most likely just the search indexing not being completely updated

Comment: That's what I figured too, but it's weird that it was working earlier...  I guess I'll wait it out.  From what I've searched, everything is set up correctly on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Duplicate Questions(Please Read):

[Google Play - Android app not showing up after 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746857/google-play-app-not-showing-up-afte-24-hours)

[My app is not showing in google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103273/my-app-is-not-showing-in-google-play)

[Why is my app not showing on Google Play? Just now published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849429/why-is-my-app-not-showing-on-google-play-just-now-published)

[App not showing up in android market place/google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835087/app-not-showing-up-in-android-market-place-google-play)

### Google Support:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/#topic=15868

### Initial Publish:

I am guessing this is your first app. New apps aren't usually going to be returned at the top of the app search.

When you first publish your application, you need to be patient and wait for Google Play to update and process your application.

For instance, your app is not found under your own developer name:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Kevin+Bright,+Inc.

I did not see it in your search your provided either:
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=interesting%20wikipedia&c=apps

The direct link should always work:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tierramaxis.interestingwikipedia

**Here are a few things to improve your visibility:**

- Ratings(I see you already rated your own app)
- Sharing your app(Social sites)
- Updating "Full Description"(To be easier to read)
- Creating a "Short Description"(Try to fill out all the fields provided by Google Play)

Answer (score -1):

Always remember that this is a game of marketing. The more you invest the more will you rise on all social & commercial sites? *Let me explain what happened when you upload an application to the*

> play store...

**You will not able to find the app when searching by its name in Google Play Store because your application is not ranked against google distribution servers.**

> The Play Store is not as easy as we think it is. So these are some
>   things to implement if you want success...

First of all, Remember that **Google won't push your app to the top** until you've had more reviews and downloads than your competitors. There are a few things you can do to try and improve your position.

1. Try to get a more **unique name for your App** (But must contain a keyword).
2. Get as many friends and family members as you can to **download and review your app**.
3. Use the name a few times in the description of your app.
4. Improve the text in your app description and info sections on the listing.
5. Give it some time and perform **ASO (APP Store Optimization)**
6. Promote your application across different platforms like **Blogs, youtube, Facebook pages.**
7. Use ad services like google ads or Facebook ads to gain organic users.

I published an application with a unique name ["Weather++"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tulip.weather) one month back and It's ranked with the help of ASO and proper keywords. It has 1000+ reviews and 50,000+ downloads in a short period of time.

So remember….

(Formula for my success)

[ASO + App Markeetring + Reviews = App Ranking](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tulip.weather)
 [ASO+ AM+ R = AR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tulip.weather)

Play store rank apps on top based on good ASO and deep links associated with apps along with downloads and reviews. (Always remember to gain organic users)