# google console account not showing in play store

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, console-application

Yesterday i have uploaded my App on google play console. Today in the console it showing that my app is published. When i click on "show" in Google Play it shows my app. But:

- there is no another app showing in suggestion
- as well as when i click on my account in google play it shows that the account not found on google play

The issue is that in google console it also not showing statistics of my app.

[This is a link to my App but when click on account NightmareSolution it not found on server](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kesebi.mobilekadata.maloom.kare)

Comment: Please take the time to learn how to properly format your posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: It may take some time. Please be patient.

Answer (score 1):

As @Muhammad Babar suggested, you need to wait since it may take some days until you see the app in Google Play Store properly. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456238/app-not-showing-in-google-play-store-even-thought-its-published-and-active-in-th) for the list of duplicate questions. When you first publish your application, you need to be patient and wait for Google Play to update and process your application.

Comment: and what the  reason behind this that my account is not opening in google play