# Why I can't find my published app on google play store?

Tags: android

About a week ago I published my app on Play store. ( **I realased the production version**. )

I can find my app by it's **package name**, ** but, **not by it's play store name****

This problem **also occurs with 3 apps more that I have published**. All of these **4 app have the same template** which I have created.

This problem only affects those 4  apps In **the past** **I published other apps that  don't face this problem**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App not showing in Google Play Store even thought its published and active in the developer console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456238/app-not-showing-in-google-play-store-even-thought-its-published-and-active-in-th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done nothing wrong. Unless you have some downloads, the play store's search algorithm ignores the app unless you search by package name.
Try [SEO](https://www.apptamin.com/blog/optimize-play-store-app/) which always helps. Try to get some downloads and ratings. Give it time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an advertising service to get you some initial downloads and Koushik is correct on what he said above.